# returning a "variable string literal" from a function

Tags: c++

I have some function that needs to return a const char* (so that a whole host of other functions can end up using it).

I know that if I had something defined as follows:

```
const char* Foo(int n)
{
    // Some code
    .
    .
    .
    return "string literal, say";
}
```

then there is no problem. However am I correct in saying that if Foo has to return some string that can only be determined at runtime (depending on the parameter n, (where each n taking any value in [0, 2^31-1] uniquely determines a return string)) then I have to use the heap (or return objects like std::string which use the heap internally)?

std::string seems too heavyweight for what I want to accomplish (at least two functions will have to pass the parcel), and allocating memory inside Foo to be freed by the caller doesn't strike me as a safe way of going forward. I cannot (easily) pass in references to the objects that need this function, and not that I believe it is possible anyway but macro trickery is out of the question.

Is there something simple that I have not yet considered?

### EDIT

Thanks to all for the answers, I'll go for std::string (I suppose in a roundabout fashion I was asking for confirmation that there is no way of hinting to the compiler that it should store the contents of some char[] in the same place that it stores string literals). As for "heavyweight" (and I'm pleasantly surprised that copying them isn't as wasteful as I thought) that wasn't the best way of putting it, perhaps "different" would have been closer to my initial apprehension.

Comment: Return an `std::string` or write a switch statement with `2^31` cases...

Comment: You can allocate memory and use smart pointers - that will be safe.

Comment: thanks, I already acknowledged that I could return a string (and I assume you were not serious about the switch! ;] )

Comment: `std::string` has a move constructor, so you don't have to copy it every time you return it.

Comment: Is `std::string` really heavy weight for your purpose? How do you know? Are you not optimizing prematurely?

Comment: You could return a pointer to a statically allocated string, but frankly, `std::string` is the obvious choice, it's not 'too heavyweight' at all. Obviously you can't actually use string *literals* unless you want to hardcode all 2 billion of them.

Comment: Not to mention, that there is no reason to return pointers, even smart pointers, when you can return a reference

Comment: Besides `std::string`'s move constructor and move assignment operator, copy elision results in less copies than you would naively expect.

Comment: if you have to return a char*, that means you should already allocated the memory in the function somewhere. then you return the char* would still persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that your function chooses between one of *n* known-at-compile-time strings, then you can just return a const char * to any one of them. A string *literal* has static storage duration in C and C++, meaning that they exist for the lifetime of the program. Therefore it is safe to return a pointer to one.

```
const char* choose_string(int n)
{
  switch(n % 4)
  {
    case 0: return "zero";
    case 1: return "one";
    case 2: return "two";
    case 3: return "three";
  }
}
```

If your function dynamically generates a string at runtime, then you have to either pass in a `(char *buf, int buf_length)` and write the result into it, or return a `std::string`.

Comment: thanks... a switch is not possible, each n uniquely determines a return string. I would agree that returning a std::string is the way forward (I wish I had been more explicit in my OP that I wanted confirmation that any search for a means to tell the compiler to store a dynamic string in the same static storage location as it does a const char* was pointless, and so I should stop looking for one)

Comment: You could store the string in a `static char result[1024]` and return a pointer to that, but that will irritate most programmers since it is non-reentrant and not thread safe and generally weird.

Comment: OP: "if Foo has to return some string that can only be determined at runtime"

Comment: @AndyThomas Well, that's ambiguously worded. It could be parsed as "of a set of constant strings, the determination of which to return can only be made at runtime."

Comment: That's true, but the OP's "2^31-1" uniquely determined strings strongly argues against a two-billion case switch statement.

Comment: @AndyThomas wow, I missed the "uniquely determined" part. You make an excellent point.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, returning a `std::string` is probably the right answer (as several others have already said).

If you don't want to use `std::string` for some reason (say, if you were programming in C, but then you would have tagged the question that way), there are several options for "returning" a string from a function. None of them are pretty.

- If you return a string literal, what you're really returning is a pointer to the first character of the array object associated with that string literal. That object has static storage duration (i.e., it exists for the entire execution of your program), so returning a pointer to it is perfectly safe. This is obviously inflexible.
- You can allocate an array on the heap and return a pointer to it. That lets the called function determine how long it needs to be, but it places the burden on the caller to deallocate the memory when it's no longer needed.
- You can return a pointer to (the first element of) a `static` array defined inside the function. This is inflexible in that the maximum length has to be determined at compile time. It also means that successive calls to the function will clobber the result. The `asctime()` function, defined in <strike>`<time.h>`</strike> `<ctime>` does this. (I once wrote a function that cycled through the elements of a static array of arrays, so that 6 successive calls would not clobber previous results, but the 7th would. That was probably overkill.)
- You can require the caller to pass in a pointer to (the first element of) an array that the caller itself must allocate, probably along with a separate argument that specifies the length of the caller's array. This requires the caller to know how long the string might be, and probably to be able to handle the error of not reserving enough space.

And now you know why C++ provides library features like `std::string` that take care of all this stuff for you.

Incidentally, the phrase "variable string literal" doesn't make a lot of sense. If something is a literal, it's not variable. Probably "variable string" is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks I agree with your points, as for my phrasing of the title, yes I think I could have done better - much better! (I meant the apostrophes to imply that what was inside them should be taken in a very loose sense).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution might be to return a `std::string`.

If you want to avoid std::string, one alternative is to have the caller pass a `char[]` buffer to the function. You might also want to provide a function that can tell the caller how big of a buffer will be needed, unless an upper bound is known statically.

Comment: Caught me mid-edit, before the bit about the size of the buffer. Yes, this introduces a risk of buffer overruns, if used poorly, in return for not using std::string or allocating memory inside the function -- as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string`, but if you really want... A common pattern used in C programming is to return the size of the final result, allocate a buffer, and call the function twice. (I apologize for the C style, you want a C solution I give a C solution :P )

```
size_t Foo(int n, char* buff, size_t buffSize)
{
  if (buff)
  {
    // check if buffSize is large enough if so fill
  }
  // calculate final string size and return
  return stringSize;
}

size_t size = Foo(x, NULL, 0); // find the size of the result
char* string = malloc(size); // allocate
Foo(x,string, size); // fill the buffer
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't advocate this method, but it will get the job done.

Comment: @JustinMeiners - You should not use `malloc` with C++

Comment: @EdHeal I agree use `new`. "I apologize for the C style, you want a C solution I give a C solution"

Comment: Bad code does not 'get the job done'. What you describe is an old C antipattern. The proper C way is either for the caller to allocate the array and pass it along with its size, or the function to allocate the array and return it to the caller.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh good call, ill edit for safety. Even so misuse in this case can still result in buffer overflows. In all cases if the programmer passes in a bad buffer, they will get bad results.

Answer (score 0):

(Donning asbestos suit)

Consider just leaking the memory.

```
const char* Foo(int n)
{
  static std::unordered_map<int, const char*> cache;
  if (!cache[n])
  {
    // Generate cache[n]
  }
  return cache[n];
}
```

Yup, this will leak memory. Up to 2^32 strings worth of them. But if you had the actual string literals, you would *always* have *all* 2^32 strings in memory (and clearly require a 64 bits build - just the \0 alone take 4GB!)

Comment: and so it begins... I'm not quite sure where in my OP I hinted that this was the kind of solution I was looking for

Comment: "simple"& "not yet considered" ? The viability of this solution depends critically on the distribution of `n`, which you haven't told us.If the function is called millions of times, but with only hundreds of values of `n`, this works. The "leak" is proportional to the number of `n` values seen, not calls.

Comment: I see, well another simple solution I hadn't considered is to perhaps have the function send an email to the person running the application and ask them what it should return! The viability of this solution of course depends on how fast and how frequently I need a solution (details I never specified of course!).
Call me paranoid but I cannot accept as reasonable the proposition that any poster with reputation approaching 62000 would ever see this as a viable solution. Especially with the reassuring comment that I would "always have all 2^32 strings in memory"

Comment: Not just viable, but similar to something that I've successfully used. Those "2^32 strings in memory" applies to the case where you'd put them in the string table, as literals. Because that table is built at compile-time and must contain all possible inputs. This table contains only the actual inputs. If you still think the idea is outlandish, check how Java String interning works.

Comment: My apologies, I completely misread this one (after the comedy suggestions I could hardcode 2 billion strings, I was a little too defensive). Looking at this a bit more carefully, if it could be proved that for the cache size to exceed some bound is unfeasibly unlikely (in so much that we have other, bigger, things to worry about if it was a possibility) then this is quite elegant. The thing is, in my short professional career, I've seen a couple too many "this can never happen" cases happen to be confident about putting that one up for code-review!